# Method parameter mismatch: Required double, no argument passed

Tags: java, bluej

I am almost complete but when I compile I get the error "Method getUserTax in class IncomeTax cannot be applied to given types; required double; found: no arguments; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length" I've gone over my code multiple times and I cannot find where the error is located. It is near the end of the code on the line "userTax = test.getUserTax();

```
import java.util.Scanner;  //Needed for the Scanner Class
/**
 * Write a description of class IncomeTax here.
 * 
 * @author CD
 * 11/30/2012
 * The IncomeTax class determines how much tax you owe based on taxable income.
 */
public class IncomeTax
{
    private int income;

    /** 
     * The constructor accepts an argument for the income field.
     */
    public IncomeTax(int i)
    {
        income = i;
    }
    /**
    * The setIncome method accepts an argument for the income field.
    */
    public void SetIncome(int i)
    {
        income = i;
    }
    /**
     * The getIncome method returns the income field.
     */
    public double getIncome()
    {
        return income;
    }
    /**
     * The getUserTax returns the tax for the income.
     */
    public static double getUserTax(double income)
    {
        double userTax = 0.10;
        if (income > 250000.0) {
            userTax = 0.35;
        } else if(income > 130000.0) {
            userTax = 0.33;
        } else if(income > 60000.0) {
            userTax = 0.28;
        } else if(income > 30000.0) {
            userTax = 0.25;
        } else if(income > 10000.0) {
            userTax = 0.15;
        }
    return userTax;
}
/**
 * This program uses the IncomeTax class to determine the Income tax for the user's 
income.
 */
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int userIncome; //To hold taxable income
    double userTax; //To hold tax

    //Create a Scanner object to read input.
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Get the Personal Income.
    System.out.print("Enter your taxable income and" + "I will tell you the income tax:");
    userIncome = keyboard.nextInt();

    //Create an IncomeTax object with the numeric score.
    IncomeTax test = new IncomeTax(userIncome);

    //Get the income tax.
    userTax = test.getUserTax();

    //Display the income tax.
    System.out.print("Your income tax is" + test.getUserTax());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userTax = test.getUserTax();
```

You need to pass `double` value as parameter to this call. Your `getUserTax` method defined as `double` type parameter required.

```
public static double getUserTax(double income)
```

Example:

`userTax = test.getUserTax(10.0);` //Here 10.0 is just for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this method signature: -

```
public static double getUserTax(double income)
```

to: -

```
public static double getUserTax()
```

You don't need to pass any `income` parameter, as that you are already having `income` as instance attribute in `IncomeTax` class. And when you invoke this method on an `IncomeTax` instance: -

```
test.getUserTax();
```

the `income` used in the method is nothing but `this.income`, which references the instance attribute.